# crontab: simple job not running

Tags: cron

I have a shell script which I am trying to run and storing the output into the text file.

```
crontab -e

MAILTO=MYEMAIL@gmail.com
* * * * * echo hello > /root/path.txt 2>&1
```

run.sh

```
echo hello
```

I was not getting the email, so I tried:

```
yum install mailx
yum install sendmail
service sendmail start
```

I am not getting `path.txt` to my email.

Comment: Silly question, but is the file well regenerated each minute ?

Comment: yes, I used `mail -s "text" <email>` and it works

Comment: Good news if your mail works, it's a prerequisite :) My (silly) question was to know if in this crontab rule, the command is well executed, observing the result file.